# How should I go about writing a Joomla! template?

Tags: templates, content-management-system, joomla

I am using Joomla! CMS to develop a website. In the not-so-distant past I customized a template to schlep up a website. It was fun and interesting to tear apart the code to de-joomla!-fy the template. So interesting that in fact, I am flirting with the idea of *making my own template from scratch*.

So, if I am to pursue this, where do I start? Do you know of any really good reference material, or should I just play with the code all day until things work out? I prefer to do tons of reading (for the concepts) before I go at it.

Comment: [Here](http://a2znotes.blogspot.in/2014/08/create-joomla-template-from-scratch.html) is a tutorial for creating joomla template from scratch.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a HTML page with the layout you want, inclusive of stylesheets and Javascript
(1.5/2.5 is Mootools based)
(Joomla 3.x is jQuery based)
[Adding Javascript](http://docs.joomla.org/Adding_JavaScript)

Keep the template initially very basic.
Save this page as index.php page.

The default directory layout is:

- css
- html
- - com_<componentname>/ mod_<modulename> (used to override the base templates of Components and Modules)
- images
- js
- templateDetails.xml
- index.php
- favicon.ico

**Change/Add the different Joomla constructs**
 Also updating the related templateDetails.xml with positions and file locations etc.
See a current template for an example of the layout.
Ex.

```
<?php
 // no direct access  
  defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die( 'Restricted access' );  
?>
```

---

**Header section:**

```
 <jdoc:include type="head" />
```

---

**Your different Modules:**

```
<?php if($this->countModules('search')) : ?>
  <jdoc:include type="modules" name="search" />
<?php endif; ?>


<jdoc:include type="module" name="breadcrumbs" />
```

**Your Main Content tag is:**

```
<jdoc:include type="component" />
```

---

**To allow your template the ability to display debug information add:**

```
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="debug" />
```

---

For more advanced additions to a template have a look at the default templates (ja_purity, Beez).
To override component and module layouts copy the layout files of the component or module into a similarly named directory below the html directory of your template and change it.

**Edit...**
**Extra utilities.**

1. To highlight the used module names in a browser add tp=1 to the end of your URL ex. yourdomain.com?tp=1
2. To View an inactive but installed Template add template=template_name. ex. yourdomain.com?template=Beez

These two can be combined, like this. yourdomain.com?template=Beez&tp=1

For more information look at:

1. [Joomla Template Tutorial Part 1 - Joomla Template Concepts](http://www.joomlaport.com/Joomla-Template-Tutorial-Part-1-Joomla-Template-Concepts.html)
2. [How to Create Your First Joomla Template](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/creating-your-first-joomla-template/)
3. [Joomla! Docs: Template Development](http://docs.joomla.org/Portal:Template_Development)
4. [Google Joomla templates](http://www.google.co.za/search?q=Joomla+Template+creation)

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer. This is an especially helpful answer.

Comment: As this post has aged a little now that Joomla at version 3.2. The Javascript you use should be jQuery not Mootools which is being slowly removed from the system

Comment: Updated to add some Joomla! 3.x information, but please check documentation for more info.

Answer (score 3):

The time-honored method of learning how to do code/templates/anything is to "steal" from someone who already knows how to do it and then modify that until:

- you're happy with the outcome; and/or
- you've learned enough to be able to go it alone.

I suggest that would be the quickest route to success. Theory is fine but you'll learn faster by doing, and making mistakes.

Comment: +1 for suggesting to 'steal' one and go from there, and then 'learn faster by doing, and making mistakes'.