# Learn Joomla in a Weekend

Tags: joomla

Long story short, I need to get up to speed with Joomla *fast*. I only have this weekend to do that which translates to about 12 hours of time. Right now I only know that Joomla is an open source CMS written in PHP. What would be the best way to familiarize myself with Joomla in this short amount of time? Official documentation? Videos? Books?

My background: I think I have a fairly decent knowledge of PHP and I'm currently learning CodeIgniter while building a simple webapp with it.

Comment: If you are more specific in what you need we can give you more specific answers.
ex. I need to do a new design for a Joomla site.   
I need to setup and run Joomla.  
I need to know the history and roadmap of...

Comment: I told you everything I knew at the time. Honest! 

The weekend has passed and I am still negotiating with the company. However, what I do know is that I will be developing websites with Joomla, probably create or modify existing templates, and write custom code to extend core Joomla functionality.

Comment: I strongly recommend you to go to the [Lynda](http://lynda.com) website and watch their online courses,you will learn it very fast,some of them are here at satckoverflow and answering the questions like:[Joseph LeBlanc]http://stackoverflow.com/users/586/jlleblanc)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was in a similar situation. I purchased "Joomla! A User's Guide: Building a Successful Joomla! Powered Website" by Barrie M. North. This was big help.

Next, I'd start out with some really good Joomla templates that were created by others. I like to learn from example, so here are the good examples I'd recommend.

1. Beez: is a free XHTML/CSS template that comes with Joomla. By default, Joomla uses TABLES for many of its modules and components. Thankfully, [Joomla Overrides](http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core) let you, well, override those ugly outputs with cleaner markup. Beez will show you how to do that and is even good enough to serve as your base.
2. Compass Designs: is the home of Barrie North, the book I recommended. He has several free templates and tutorials.
3. YOOtheme: Will cost you something, but you will get both good example templates and some handy AJAX tools to use as Joomla Extensions.

Comment: I don't think the company cares the least bit about markup as long as the customer likes it, but I will surely check out Beez at some point. And welcome to the SO.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend [this eBook](http://www.learnjoomla.co.uk/) from personal experience.

Here are some more resources:

- [Learn Joomla 1.5 Fast!](http://help.joomla.org/files/VisualGuide15.pdf)
- [EHow.com's Tutorial](http://www.ehow.com/how_2280856_learn-joomla.html)
- [MyJoomlaGuide.com](http://www.myjoomlaguide.com/)

Good Luck!

Comment: ...while you wait for your book or when you are not reading it go to Joomla forum and start reading all those "How do I" posts, starting from the tasks you are most likely to do.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to do templates have look at this post and my answer.
[How should I go about writing a Joomla! template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061670/how-should-i-go-about-writing-a-joomla-template)

Answer (score 2):

Since you do not have a book yet and you must not loose time Google this "Joomla Quick Start" and you'll find a few interesting links.

Also, [here is a Joomla Quick Start](http://help.joomla.org/ghop/feb2008/task048/joomla_15_quickstart.pdf), in PDF format, from Joomla web site, that you can start reading right away.

Answer (score 2):

There are plenty of "free" books on Google Books with lots of information!

[Joomla building a Successful Site](http://books.google.de/books?id=ncLrNhwkNwEC&pg=PA1&dq=joomla&lr=lang_en&as_drrb_is=q&as_minm_is=0&as_miny_is=&as_maxm_is=0&as_maxy_is=&as_brr=0) / [Joomla visual Quickstart](http://books.google.de/books?id=0ubnV7vSHPkC&pg=PP1&dq=joomla&lr=lang_en&as_drrb_is=q&as_minm_is=0&as_miny_is=&as_maxm_is=0&as_maxy_is=&as_brr=0) .. try it for yourself
[Google Books Joomla](http://books.google.de/books?lr=lang_en&as_drrb_is=q&as_minm_is=0&as_miny_is=&as_maxm_is=0&as_maxy_is=&q=joomla&as_brr=0&sa=N&start=10)

Answer (score 2):

Dan Rahmel's Professional Joomla is the most insightful book on Joomla. It really helped me to master Joomla template creation. All examples in the book relate to Joomla 1.5.

http://img41.imageshack.us/img41/6817/400000000000000150648s4.jpg