# Beginner: Do I have to use templates when implementing my own designs using CMS such as Joomla?

Tags: templates, content-management-system, joomla

Brand new to CMS:

With Joomla or other CMS, If I want to use my own design, do I have to make it a template first using proprietary code of some sort = ie using some Joomla templating language - or is using my own design with Joomla simple and independent?

I am not sure the role "templates" play with Joomla and other CMS. I gather they can be used as a complete "pre-made" design where you just tweak it, but are they necessary as a base of some sort to using my own designs?  I am proficient with HTML and CSS.  I also have been playing around with various Jquery Plugin's for my UI.

Ideally I would like to create any design I can think of with any layout I create and use CMS simply for its database and plugins etc such as a blog or calender back end. I might use it for more features as I learn about them. Do I need to use a "template" or create a "template" to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

{edit}
You have to create a template (or change an existing one), how else will the CMS know where to add the information into as the template is a HTML, CSS and Javascript Page group devoid of information and some HTML Tags replaced with CMS Specific tags, which tells the CMS where to add the information. It also include certain files telling the CMS the Name, and othe information of the template.

1. The First step in creating a template is to have a design.
2. Do your design in HTML and CSS. (Preferably using the CMS Template folder/directory structure.)
3. For Joomla use the information in this post: [How should I go about writing a Joomla! template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061670/how-should-i-go-about-writing-a-joomla-template/1064126#1064126)

In Joomla jQuery have to be used in compatibility mode.
The CMS will supply the information, you supply the design and tell the CMS

{/edit}
The Template is the design container, whether you create one from scratch or reuse a current template. I initially used one of the pre-installed templates (together with the documentation) to learn some of the complexities of designing the template. (ex. structure, and what is possible.)

Please also look at my answer to this question [How should I go about writing a Joomla! template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061670/how-should-i-go-about-writing-a-joomla-template/1064126#1064126) as it is a pretty good beginners guideline for template designers in Joomla (Even if I have to say it myself) with a couple of other resources linked in as well.

Answer (score 1):

A Joomla template is nothing but HTML layout stylised using CSS. So to create your own templates you need a good grasp on HTML and CSS.

Joomla, by default provides a couple of templates to start with.

If you are just beginning, creating your own template is not where you want to start...learn more about setting up Joomla. You have enough problems there :)

Comment: that is helpful.  Can u recommend where i can find a place to get started setting it up where, or the best place?  There are so many different places it seems to "get started" with Joomla.

Answer (score 1):

[Joomla! 1.5: A User's Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0137012314) is a great beginner book. It takes you through learning Joomla, what templates are, how to make them, and even walks you through setting up WAMP so you can experiment on your local machine.

The templates only affect the styling of your site.  If you are starting out, I would work on getting your content in place first and wait on templates until later on.

Comment: I totally appreciate the advice on the user guide and what i can expect to get from it.  I'm such a rookie that i wasn't even sure what to expect in the user's guide.  I haven't wanted to invest too much time until i know, hence my asking on here.  

One thing though:  I am a designer first, and I want to use CMS to help me become a better developer... so with that said, in response to "work on getting your content in place first and wait on templates until later" is this a good idea?

Comment: oh i should add i guess:  Design is very important to me, so I want to make sure whatever content i get in place can work with my designs.  I suppose my question should be more relating to how should i think about this when it comes to templates.

Comment: Whatever content you have, whether your content is a blog article, a photo gallery or a video player, it will get wrapped up in a Joomla "container"...as an article, or a module or whatever.  And those containers will basically display in any template.  The template will apply CSS and positioning rules to the box containing your content, and that's it.  Your content still controls all its own functionality within its own box.

Answer (score 0):

My experience has been revamping my two websites to use WordPress, then moving to ModX, then moving back to HTML.  I believe that you don't need a template but it will make some things easier as it bundles a lot of stuff you'd otherwise have to do manually. --At least for WordPress.  I'm not even sure we found a good ModX template but adapted [poorly] a WordPress one.  ModX is a good but little known CMS.

With one of my sites I found that it was impossible for WordPress to handle the images, thus I began working with a plug-in developer to create a custom plug-in.  He took about a year and it still wasn't useable.  Also I hired some consultants along the way.  Their biggest contribution was "to complexify things" so I couldn't make any changes myself without going back to them & paying hundreds of $ to change a phone # for example.

I chucked all that and redid everything in HTML5 with Javascript, css and a little php. People here on S.Overflow actually helped me with the coding. I have a 3rd simple site that I may go back to WordPress for but only to use some particular functions which might be a pain to program otherwise.

Here is one of my 2 HTML sites:
[coinsandhistory.com](https://coinsandhistory.com)