# Joomla position in a template

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5

In Joomla, for any template that we use, we have a number of specified positions
( left, right, footer) .. Is it possible to include new position in the template which suits our choice ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is.
You need to add a div element in the place you need and insert joomla tag

```
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="yuor_position_name" style="xhtml" />
```

in it.
Than you need to add this position to your templateDetails.xml
Edit this file and add to the <positions> section one more thread like this:

```
<position>your_position_name</position>
```

and save the file. From now you will see this position in modules setup.
Good tutorial about Joomla 1.5 templates you can read here:
http://www.compassdesigns.net/joomla-tutorials/joomla-15-template-tutorial

Comment: I also wrote a basic tutorial on templates here on stackoverflow,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061670/how-should-i-go-about-writing-a-joomla-template/1064126#1064126,
I also added the above link to the tutorial.

Comment: @elisium: I see you've made a typo in the jdoc name="yuor_..., should be jdoc name="your_...

Comment: Sorry, didn't catch what you mean about typo… Language problems :)